# XSD class generation using XJC produces dead code for Boolean values

Tags: xsd, xjc

I have the following XDS that represents various metadata item types:

```
<xs:simpleType name="BooleanTypeKey">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="isValue1" />
    <xs:enumeration value="isValue2" />
    <xs:enumeration value="isValue3" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:complexType name="BooleanType">
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:boolean">
      <xs:attribute name="key" type="BooleanTypeKey" use="required" />
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Using the following xjc to produce my classes:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>myId</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>xjc</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <packageName>com.myorg.packagename.model</packageName>
            <schemaDirectory>/src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
            <bindingDirectory>/src/main/resources/xjb</bindingDirectory>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated/jaxb</outputDirectory>
            <extension>true</extension>
            <enableIntrospection>true</enableIntrospection>
            <arguments>-Xequals -xhasCode -xtoString</arguments>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
          <version>0.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

This produces the following class for the BooleanType object:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "BooleanType", propOrder = {
    "value"
})
public class BooleanType implements Equals, HashCode, ToString
{
  @XmlValue
  protected Boolean value;
  @XmlAttribute(name = "key", required = true)
  protected BooleanTypeKey key;

  //... getters and setters ...

  public boolean equals(ObjectLocator thisLocator, ObjectLocator thatLocator, Object object, EqualsStrategy strategy) {

    //... basic object checks ...

    final BooleanType that = ((BooleanType) object);
    {
// This is NOT part of the generated code
// Why does the next 2 lines look like they do??? It should only read:
// boolean lhsValue = this.isValue();
// The fact that there is a check for *true*
//     (constant value check... really???)
// Not only is this completely useless, but it causes dead code production (the else part (false)).
      boolean lhsValue;
      lhsValue = (true?this.isValue():false);
      boolean rhsValue;
      rhsValue = (true?that.isValue():false);
      //...more code ...
    }
    //...more code ...
  }
}
```

Can someone tell me if I can avoid producing such code, I am using a faulty version of xjc? A version that is too old?

Thanks,